# Evaluate the integral $\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^2+2z}{z^2+4}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^2+2z}{z^2+4}dz$$ where the contour $\gamma$ is

1.) the circle of radius $2$ centered at $2i$, traversed once anti-clockwise.

2.) the unit circle centered at the origin, traversed once anti-clickwise.

So here we would have to use partial fractions: $$1+ \frac{2z-4}{z^2+4}.$$

Then for part 1.), $\gamma(t)=2 e^{it}+2i$.

And for part 2.), $\gamma(t)= e^{it}$.

I'm not sure what to do next to evaluate the integral for part 1.) and 2.).

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\int _\gamma f$?

Comment: Would that involve the Cauchy formula?

Comment: Are you allowed to use residue calculus?

Comment: No. Do you know that $\int _\gamma f=\int \limits_0^{2\pi}f(e^{-i\theta})\cdot (-i)e^{-i\theta}\mathrm d\theta$?

Comment: 'DepeHb': I think we're meant to use Cauchy's Integral Theorem.
'Git Gud': I can't say I am familiar with that definition.
Is what I've done so far correct? And what would be the next logical step?

Comment: The next step would be to either use what I mentioned above or, and it seems that you want, use Cauchy's Integral Formula, but in order to do this you need to use partial fractions, which you haven't. You just separated the sum in two fractions. Other possibilies come to mind, but you don't seem to be ready for them. May I ask what text book are you using?

Comment: It's called Complex Analysis by Stewart and Tall. And I'll take another look at my partial fractions as they are incorrect.

Comment: I've changed my partial fractions. Is this now correct?

Comment: The quality is correct, it was correct before too. But what you want to do is rewrite $\dfrac{2z-4}{z^2+4}$ as $\dfrac {}{z-2i}+\dfrac {}{z+2i}$ for some denominators yet to be determined. Once you do that you can try to use Cauchy's Integral Formula.

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$ Apply the residue theorem. $\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^2+2z}{(z-2i)(z+2i)}dz=2i\pi(\sum res_{z=z_k})$. Define $z_0:=z+2i.$ Thus, $res_{z=z_0}f(z)=\frac{z_k^2+2z_k}{2z_k}$, for $k=0$.

$(2)$ Notice that none of your singluar points are in your contour $\Rightarrow $$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z^2+2z}{(z-2i)(z+2i)}dz=0$, by Cauchy Integral Formula.